# Right way to separate Oauth2 Authorization server from the web application

Tags: spring-boot, oauth, authorization

I have some SPA in Vue, with Spring boot backend. I'd like to utilize OAuth2 with JWT so far there is couple of tutorials which I can [use](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-oauth-jwt). In future I want to add more applications and also enable the Single Sign On for their users.

So I'd like to take step ahead and separate the authorization server part. The question is to which server should the SPA applications communicate.

1. Communicate login to the Authorization server to get the JWT directly
2. Communicate login to their backend which will forward the call to the Authorization server

I found https://github.com/OhadR/oAuth2-sample where all is separated, but I'm quite confused about the communication behind the scenes. They seems to communicate directly(as in 1.).

There is one advantage to 2. I will not need to change the SPA later when I will separate the authorization to different server.

I'm worried that the correct solution is to add some gateway(another server) to the mix.

Comment: 1 is the right answer.  You should not be passing a user's password around from place to place: that is not Oauth.  The password should go directly to the authorisation server from the user agent as described in the Oauth spec.  Passwords and refresh tokens are high vale secrets, and never get passed to resource servers.

Comment: Can you please help me to clarify one more thing. Using JWT tokens, nothing else then Authorization server public key is needed to be shared to Resource server(to be able to verify the token), right?Or does resource server somehow communicate to the authorization server? Maybe only for non-PKI schemes.

Comment: that is correct, the benefit of JWT implementation is resource server does not need to communicate with authorisatio server for every access request.  The original Oauth spec treats this authorisation check out of scope.  But self-contained tokens like JWTs allow you to do the check without a separate communication.